# What's wrong with the following solution for changing an array so that it becomes non-decreasing?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

What I am expecting is not the exact answer but the ways in which I can improve the solution.
Currently its plain wrong, its not passing even a single test case.
In one case it gives wrong answer and others it shows Timeout.

**Problem**

Given an array A of size N. Its to be converted into an array so that A[i - 1] < A[i] where i belongs to [2, N]. We can add X to any element of this array any number of times. Our task is to tell the minimum number of such addition of X are required in order to get A[i-1] < A[i] condition satisfied.

**Input**

First line of the input will contain T(No. of test cases).
    For every test case, first line will contain two space separated integers denoting N and X. Next line will contain N space separated integers denoting A[i].

**Output**

For every test case, print the required answer in a new line.

**Sample Input**

```
2    // Total Number of Test Cases
2 1    // First value is N and second is X
1 1    // Elements of the first Array
3 1    // First value is N and second is X for the second array
1 1 2  // Elements of the second array
```

**Sample Output**

```
1
2
```

My Solution :-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;


class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int T = Integer.parseInt(line);// Total number of Test Cases
        int N = 0;// Number of elements in the Array
        int X = 0;// The number which can be added to the elements of the array
        int[] arr;
        int count;// Final count value which needs to be shown
        while(T-->0) {
            String[] str = br.readLine().trim().split("\\s+");
            N= Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
            X = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
            arr = new int[N];
            str = br.readLine().trim().split("\\s+");
            count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
                arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
            }

            for(int i = 1; i < N ; i++){
                while(arr[i - 1] >= arr[i]){
                    arr[i] += X;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }


    }
}
```

For the above sample input the answer the above code is generating is correct but it fails in other cases which are hidden by the online judge and also it gives timeout.
How to fix this?

Comment: well without knowing what the mystery inputs are and actual stacktraces with the error messages no one will be able to help you.

Comment: You are right. What I am expecting are the different ways to improve the code by doing things in more correct way. I would accept that as answer.

Comment: I don't think it should go to code review, as the solution is not correct, unless its correct I don't think the question of reviewing arises.

Comment: @AniMenon As a moderator on Code Review, I think that at the moment this does not belong on Code Review. If the problem is that it **fails** on the online judge (i.e. gives bad results), it is off-topic. If the problem **only is** that it gives **timeout**, then it is on-topic. Judging from [what the OP said in a comment:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811789/whats-wrong-with-the-following-solution-for-changing-an-array-so-that-it-become#comment61196824_36811789) *the solution is not correct*, and therefore off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: they edited the question, it originally said the code worked but not on some mystery input that was hidden even from the OP. Original question said *For the above sample input the answer the above code is generating is correct but it fails in other cases which are hidden by the online judge and also it gives timeout. How to fix this?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two potential issues:

Firstly, you have a while loop inside your for loop.  You should be able to compute the number of iterations directly using a divison instead of a loop.  This should avoid the timeouts.

Let us use k to represent the number of iterations of the while loop.
We know that

```
A[i]+k*x > A[i-1].
```

Therefore we can deduce

```
k > (A[i-1]-A[i])/x
```

Using integer arithmetic the number of iterations around the loop can be computed as:

```
k = (A[i-1]-A[i]+x)/x if A[i] <= A[i-1], or 0 otherwise
```

Secondly, be careful about integer overflow.  It is not clear how large X and N can be, but check that the largest value won't overflow your int datatype.

Comment: Please kindly elaborate more on the divison you are talking about.

Comment: @JohnDoe I've added some more explanation of the division